# .Net Core 2.0 Configuration with lists

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to bind a list of ids to a setting and it works when I use bind however retrieving it with GetValue is not working. i.e this works:

```
var authenticationSettings = new Authentication();

this.Configuration.GetSection("Authentication").Bind(authenticationSettings);

var clients = authenticationSettings.AuthorizedApplications;
```

This does not:

```
var authenticationSettings = this.Configuration.GetValue<Authentication>("Authentication");
```

And this does not work

```
var clients = this.Configuration.GetValue<List<string>>("Authentication:AuthorizedApplications");
```

Here is my configuration class:

```
public class Authentication
{
    public List<string> AuthorizedApplications { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this article about [configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration):

> GetValue is for simple scenarios and does not bind to entire
>   sections. GetValue gets scalar values from GetSection(key). Value
>   converted to a specific type.

That's why you should use `Bind()` extension method that provides functionality of binding whole configuration sections to strongly typed c# objects.

Some time ago I've developed following extension method that allows to get a section in one line of code:

```
public static class ConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static T GetSectionValue<T>(this IConfiguration configuration, string sectionName) where T : new()
    {
        var val = new T();
        configuration.GetSection(sectionName).Bind(val);
        return val;
    }
}

var authenticationSettings = Configuration.GetSectionValue<Authentication>("Authentication");
var listValue = Configuration.GetSectionValue<List<string>>("Authentication:AuthorizedApplications");
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. Just use `Configuration.GetSection("SectionName").Get<SectionType>();`